# How can I check INITIALIZE UPDATE and EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE correctness?

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

[image]

I sent `80 50 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` [**INITILIZE UPDATE** Command] via opensc-tool to my java card and received `00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9 FF 02 00 11 79 11 36 5D 71 00 A5 A5 EC 63 BB DC 05 CC` [**Init Response**] as its response from the card.

As you see:

In the command,I send `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` as **Host Challenge**, And in the response :

`00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9` = **Key diversification data**

`FF 02` = **Key information**

`00 11 79 11 36 5D 71 00` = **Card challenge**

`A5 A5 EC 63 BB DC 05 CC` = **Card cryptogram**

Now I want to check myself,if the card cryptogram is OK or not. How I can do it? for example I encrypt `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` in [this](http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/) site under a 3DES cryptography algorithm [with keys of my card = `4041...4F`], but the output is not equal with card cryptogram that I wrote above. Why?

And the next question is, if I want to send **EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATION** command to the card, what is its data field (after the above INITILIZE UPDATE)?

**Update:**

This is GPJ output :

```
C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>GPJ
C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>java -jar gpj.jar
Found terminals: [PC/SC terminal ACS CCID USB Reader 0]
Found card in terminal: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00
.
.
.
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00
Successfully selected Security Domain OP201a A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 7F 41 A9 E7 19 37 83 FA
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9 FF 02 00 1B 9B 95 B9 5E 5E BC BA 51 34 84 D9 C1 B9 6E 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 10 13 3B 4E C5 2C 9E D8 24 50 71 83 3A 78 AE 75 23
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 08 13 3B 4E C5 2C 9E D8 24
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00

C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>
```

**So :**

```
Host_Challenge :: 7F41A9E7193783FA

Diversification_Data :: 0000116001008A790AF9

Key_Information :: FF02

Sequence_Counter :: 001B

Card_Challenge :: 9B95B95E5EBC

Card_Cryptogram :: BA513484D9C1B96E

Host_Cryptogram[16,24] = 13 3B 4E C5 2C 9E D8 24
```

**Now,lets make our Host_Cryptogram Manually :**

```
Derivation_data=derivation_const_ENC|sequence_counter|0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Derivation_Data = 0182001B000000000000000000000000

k_ENC :: 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F

IV = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

S_ENC = encrypt(TDES_CBC, K_ENC, IV, derivation_data)
```

**So :**

I used http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/ and its output for above values was :

```
S_ENC = 448b0a5967ca246d058703ff0c694f15
```

**And :**

```
Padding_DES = 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Host_auth_data = sequence_counter | card_challenge | host_challenge | padding_DES
IV = Card_Cryptogram :: BA513484D9C1B96E
host_cryptogram = encrypt(TDES_CBC, S_ENC, IV, host_auth_data)
```

**So :**

```
Host_Authentication_Data : 001B9B95B95E5EBC7F41A9E7193783FA8000000000000000
```

Again, I used http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/

**and :**

```
Host_Cryptogram : 3587b531db71ac52392493c08cff189ce7b9061029c63b62
```

**So :**

```
Host_Cryptogram[16,24] = e7b9061029c63b62
```

**Why these two way [manually and GPJ output] give us two host cryptogram?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the INITIALIZE UPDATE command you send, you get

```
host_challenge = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In response to the INITIALIZE UPDATE command, you get

```
diversification_data = 00 00 11 60 01 00 8A 79 0A F9
key_information = FF 02
sequence_counter = 00 11
card_challenge = 79 11 36 5D 71 00
card_cryptogram = A5 A5 EC 63 BB DC 05 CC
```

The key information indicates SCP02 (`02`). The key diversification data may be used to derive the card-specific K_ENC. Lets assume we have a K_ENC like this

```
K_ENC = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

We can then derive the session encryption key like this

```
derivation_const_ENC = 01 82
derivation_data = derivation_const_ENC | sequence_counter |  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

IV = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
S_ENC = encrypt(TDES_CBC, K_ENC, IV, derivation_data)
```

Next, we can assemble the authentication data used to calculate the host cryptogram:

```
padding_DES = 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
host_auth_data = sequence_counter | card_challenge | host_challenge | padding_DES
```

Then we can use the session encryption key to encrypt the authentication data:

```
IV = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
host_cryptogram = encrypt(TDES_CBC, S_ENC, IV, host_auth_data)
```

The last 8 bytes of the encrypted authentication data are the actual host cryptogram that we would send to the card:

```
EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE_data = host_cryptogram[16, 24]
```

Now we can assemble the EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE command:

```
EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE = 84 82 03 00 08 | EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE_data
```

We can then calculate the S_MAC key (analoguous to getting the S_ENC above) and the MAC over that command and append it to the command data to get the full EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE command that can be sent to the card:

```
EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE = 84 82 03 00 10 | EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATE_data | MAC
```

---

### Update

**Using http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/ to reproduce the results of GPJ**

Your K_ENC is `404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F`. The online tools does not properly support 2-key-3DES, so you have to convert the key into its 3-key form first:

```
K_ENC = 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F4041424344454647
```

Use this key and a zero IV to encrypt the derivation data (`0182001B000000000000000000000000`). You get

```
S_ENC = fb063cc2e17b979b10e22f82110234b4
```

In 3-key notation, this is

```
S_ENC = fb063cc2e17b979b10e22f82110234b4fb063cc2e17b979b
```

Use this key and a zero IV to encrypt the host authentication data (`001b9b95b95e5ebc7f41a9e7193783fa8000000000000000`):

```
HOST_CRYPTOGRAM = 773e790c91acce3167d99f92c60e2afd133b4ec52c9ed824
```

Comment: what is **K_ENC**? I searched GP **Spec 2.2** and GP **Spec 2.1** for it, and find nothing! Is there any default value for it or we set any value that we want?

Comment: sorry Micheal, but, in line `host_cryptogram = encrypt(TDES_CBC, S_ENC, IV, card_auth_data)`, what is **card_auth_data**? is it the card challenge random number? thank you.

Comment: K_ENC is the card's key for encryption. That's whatever you or the card manufacturer set it to. It could for instance be `40 41 .. 4F` (or a card-specific key derived by using a master key).

Comment: That should be `host_auth_data`.

Comment: Ooops, :( Dear Mr Roland, I use the above formulas step by step and also http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/  for **JC Manager** outputs, but I receive a different **Host Cryptogram** from the one that **JC Manager** made! why?

Comment: And, What is the **MAC** that comes in the end of `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` command? how I can create the MAK? Thank you.

Comment: did you try to google these questions before posting questions to SO?

Comment: @PaulBastian :  yes I google it! would you please give me your email address? I want to send you a word file that explain the question more clear. I think this is a better Idea instead of ask it here.

Comment: the **M** essage **A** uthentication **C** ode ensures integrity and authenticity. in case of of SCP02 this is described in GP2.2 E.4.4 APDU Command C-MAC Generation and Verification

Comment: dear @PaulBastian , when I calculate `Host_Cryptogram` with above formulas and using this site[http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/], the output is different than what jcmanager send to the card with **EXTERNAL_AUTHENTICATION** APDU command. this is my main question.

Comment: @PaulBastian
please take a look at **Update** section that I added to the question.

Comment: @abraham I was wrong about the IV for encrypting the host cryptogram. A zero IV should be used. See my updated answer on how to calculate the cryptogram.

Comment: @MichaelRoland thank you. Is this right? --> "In the **GPJ** and **JCManager**, the tool automatically use first 8 byte of the key [`404142...4F`] for fisrt and third **DES** and use second 8 byte for second **DES** of **3DES** process. but in the online tool, when I give it `404142...4F` as its key, it use first 8 byte for first **DES**, second 8 byte for second **DES**, and `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` for last **DES**" And this was origin of the problem?

Comment: Is the `diversification data` value always the same? What would make it change in value?

Comment: Hey @MichaelRoland Can you provide detailed explanation for creating S_MAC?